# Smooth gradient in fragment shader

Tags: opengl, shader, fragment-shader

I am looking for some way how to get smooth gradient with fragment shader. I have palette with `11` colors and `value` which used to define color (it lays in range from `0.0` to `1.0`).

I am trying to get smooth color translation with such `fragment shader`:

```
#version 150 core

in float value;    
uniform vec3 colors[11];

out vec4 out_Color;

void main(void) 
{
    int index = int(round(value * 10));

    int floorIndex = 0; 

    if (index != 0) floorIndex = index - 1;

    out_Color = vec4(mix(colors[floorIndex], colors[index], value), 1.0f);
}
```

But using such approach I could get only stepped colors distribution.

[image]

And my desirable result looks like:

[image]

I know how to get this with path-through shader just passing color as attribute, but this is not that way. I am going to get such smooth distribution with single float value passed to `fragment shader`.

Comment: A suggestion: change `if (index != 0) floorIndex = index - 1;` to `floorIndex = max(index-1, 0)` to avoid the branch and increase performance.

Comment: @Colonel Thirty Two: really, nice suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mixing function is not really usefully applied here:

```
mix(colors[floorIndex], colors[index], value)
```

The problem is that, while `value` is in [0,1], it is not the proper mixing factor. You need it to be scaled to [0,1] for the *sub-range* you have selected. E.g, your code uses `floorIndex=2` and `index=3` when value is in [0.25, 0.35), so now you need a mix factor wich is 0.0 when value is 0.25, 0.5 when it is 0.3 and goint near 1.0 when it reaches 0.35 (at 3.5 the round will switch to the next step, of course).

So you will need something like:

```
float blend=(value * 10.0) - float(floorIndex) - 0.5;
mix(colors[floorIndex], colors[index], blend)
```

That can probably be optimized a bit by using the [`fract()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/fract.xhtml) operation.

Another thing which comes to mind is that you could use a (1D) texture for your palette and enable `GL_LINEAR` filtering. In that case, you can directly use `value` as texture coordinate and will get the result you need. This will be much simpler, and likely also more efficient as it moves most of the operations to the specialised texture sampling hardware. So if you don't have a specific reason for not using a texture, I strongly recommend doing that.

Comment: your variant with blend gives exactly what I was looking for. thanks!